# Android: When I scroll the screen to top, why the scroll stop on Toolbar?

Tags: android

I'm using the follow code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ferias_janeiro"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView ... >
```

When I scroll the screen from bottom to top, the scroll stop at begin of NestedScrollView, I must scroll again to expand the CollapsingToolbarLayout. How can I fix that?

The effect is the same of the contact screen of the Android, when I scroll the screen from bottom to top, the screen hit the top and show the contact image (CollapsingToolbarLayout full expanded).

Answer (score 0):

Remove app:layout_collapseMode="pin" from the Toolbar